# Angularjs call $scope.function from plain JS function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recaptcha

I am trying to implement a google recapcha,
I am able to verify user is Human with the help of it,

The reCapcha code is calling Callback function named 'verifyCallback'in my code,
Further I want to call an AngularJS fucntion written in my controller scope.

Here are my codes so far -

Main Html , I've included-

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

**Html partial -**

```
    var onloadCallback = function() 
    {
        grecaptcha.render('loginCapcha', {
            'sitekey' : 'someKey',
            'callback' : verifyCallback,
            'theme':'dark'

        });
    };

    var verifyCallback = function(response) 
    {
        //I get a response if user is able to solve the Capcha challenge
        console.log(response);

        //I want to call the function called 'auth' written in my AngularJS controller
        var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('#loginCapcha')).scope();
        scope.auth();
    };

    <div id="loginCapcha"></div>
```

**AngularJS Controller -**

```
var _myApp = angular.module('homeApp',[]);

_myApp.controller('loginController',['$scope',
 function($scope){

    $scope.auth = function()
    {
        console.log("Auth called");
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I think a best solution is to use the recaptcha JS API directly instead of doing the generic setup here.  There are a few recaptcha directives if you search around but not sure which one is most up to date and/or bug free at this point.  https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api    here's one http://vividcortex.github.io/angular-recaptcha/

Comment: @shaun thanks for the links, I was trying to implement a basic working code, I'll Look into your given links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div ng-controller='loginController' id='yourControllerElementID'> 

</div>
```

For above scenario, use following code:

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('yourControllerElementID')).scope();
scope.auth();
```

So, your method will look like this:

```
var verifyCallback = function(response) 
    {
        //I get a response if user is able to solve the Capcha challenge
        console.log(response);

        //I want to call the function called 'auth' written in my AngularJS controller
        var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('#yourControllerElementID')).scope();
        scope.auth();
    };
```

Comment: 'yourControllerElementID' is my controller name or the function name inside my controller?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje Updated answer, please check.

Comment: I edited the code, it's giving me a - Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje Updated my answer, I made a mistake. Just remove `#`. Replace `document.getElementById('#loginCapcha')` with `document.getElementById('loginCapcha')`

Comment: One more thing, I don't see any controller in your `div`. `<div id="loginCapcha"></div>` should be something like `<div ng-controller='loginController' id="loginCapcha"></div>`.

Comment: I am using ng-route , so controller is applied from there, and ng-app is applied on main html.